# How would I open a dialog.showSaveDialog in the Electron render process without the use of remote?

Tags: electron

How would I open a dialog.showSaveDialog in the Electron render process without the use of remote? Starting with Electron 14 the `render` module is no longer available and it seems discouraged using the `@electron/remote` as well, so I was wondering what the "proper" way currently is.

Comment: I think it boils down to usage of `ipcRenderer` via a preload script and letting the main process handle the dialog, that's at least the most comfortable way I found -- don't know whether that is best practice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

In main

```
ipcMain.handle('some-handler', async (event, someConfig) => {
   const result = await someFuncThatDoesYourContextMenu(someConfig);
   return result;
}
```

In renderer

```
const result = await ipcRenderer.invoke('some-handler', someConfig);
```